# Finding unique combination of two columns where each value appears once

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

I'm trying to set up a game matchup where each player plays only once and maximize the number of games total. Out of the 15 possible matchups I'm trying to figure out what combination of p1,p2 to select.

The code I've tried:
Attempt 1

```
with cte1 as(
select p1,p2,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by p1 order by (select 0) desc) rn 
from #tempgame
) ,cte2 as (select p1,p2,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by p2 order by (select 0) desc) rn 
from cte1
where rn=1
)select * from cte2
where rn = 1
```

Attempt 2:

```
    select distinct a.p2,b.p1
    from #tempgame a
    join #tempgame b
    on a.p1 = 
            ( select top 1 a.p1
            from #tempgame b
            where b.p2 = a.p2

            )
```

I haven't even managed to get it to a point where it fulfills the first condition of each player playing only once let alone maximizing the amount of matchups.

I've determined already based on player availability that only these matchups are possible and took the midrange of their availability to determine gametime. So I can't just take the players table and assign them at random if their available timeframes don't overlap. So the question is simple: what p1,p2 combination is allowed based on the simple p1,p2 table?

```
select * 
INTO #tempgame
from (
select  76561197987822470 p1,76561198040907827 p2 union all 
select 76561197987822470,76561198088336999 union all
select 76561197987822470,76561198095503172 union all
select 76561197987822470,76561198397303730 union all
select 76561198001599297,76561198397303730 union all
select 76561198001599297,76561198321977951 union all
select 76561198001599297,76561198095503172 union all
select 76561198040907827,76561198088336999 union all
select 76561198040907827,76561198095503172 union all
select 76561198040907827,76561198397303730 union all
select 76561198088336999,76561198397303730 union all
select 76561198088336999,76561198095503172 union all
select 76561198095503172,76561198397303730 union all
select 76561198095503172,76561198321977951 union all
select 76561198321977951,76561198397303730 
) z
```

I believe only 2 matchups are possible. I don't care which ones. But I wasn't able to find a logical way of calculating this other than trial and error on a small sample.

```
      P1                           P2
row1 76561197987822470 vs 76561198040907827
row2 76561198001599297 vs 76561198397303730
```

Comment: I've added a simple temp table I think that's easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, deleted the image and cleaned up the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to set up a game matchup where each player plays only once and maximize the number of games total.

If this is your goal, start with the *player* tables and use a self-join:

```
select p1.player_id, p2.player_id
from players p1 join
     players p2
     on p1.player_id < p2.player_id
```

I'm not sure what `gametime` has to do with the question -- or in fact what the data or query really have to do with it.

Comment: That wouldn't work because it would ignore the player availability. I've wrote a longer query that takes the midvalue (gametime) of their overlapping available date ranges and put it as an allowed matchup. I've updated my original post with sample data and more explanation of expected result.